# Filterizr, applying a filter on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am using Filterizr for a portfolio.
http://yiotis.net/filterizr/#docs
I have 5 categories, which I have buttons for, that apply filters on click.
I am initialising with the following code:

```
<script>
    var filterizd = $('.filtr-container').filterizr({
    layout: 'packed'
    });
</script>
```

The filters all work perfectly.
But, when the page initially loads, no filters are applied, and so all the images load and it's far too many.
I would like to have the script load one of my filters when the page initially loads - so prior to any of the filter buttons actually clicked:

```
data-filter="1"
```

I suspect that something could be added to the script options along with my layout option, but I couldn't see anything on the page documentation.

Appreciate any help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the initial filter in the options object to the category you want to display on init, just like this:

```
<script>
    var filterizd = $('.filtr-container').filterizr({
    filter: 1,
    layout: 'packed'
    });
</script>
```

This would initialize your gallery with category nr 1 set to active.

Comment: In my case I have to put `filter: '1'` instead `filter: 1` to work. I use Filterizr version 2.2.3.